# setegid() in a suid-root binary in C

Tags: c, system-calls, setuid

Good evening,
I am trying to write a suid-root binary in C and I have stumbled across the following problem:
I execute it as a non-privileged user user1 and I am able to use setuid/seteuid to change to any user id I want. The problem is that I can't do that with effective group ids. 
Part of code:

```
if ( setegid(VariableID) == -1 ) {
    perror("setegid failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

and this returns:

```
setegid failed: Operation not permitted
```

Please note that I can successfully change group IDs between root(0) and the user that executes the binary but I can't change to other groups. Shouldn't this be possible since the binary is suid-root like the UID/EUID?

Comment: change group first, then user

Comment: Could you please provide some more info about why is this happening?

Comment: As far as I understand, if you change the user first, that user might not have the permission to change the group ID, while if you're root, you can certainly do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (thanks Ingo Leonhardt) is that you need to change the group id before the user id. It kind of makes sense now.. :)